# How Custom membership provider can be used in Asp .Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use my own table for user login and role in asp .net MVC 5. So that I can get Custom identity value in controller and can check authentication and authorization in controller.

I see these
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/G54G220114-Custom-Authentication-and-Authorization-in-ASP.NET-MVC.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx

but can not get good answer any body can help me?

Comment: What have you tried already? Mark-up and existing code attempts will aid in getting you more help, see: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Look at System.Web.Security.Membership

I would register the user on your database using EF then call the CreateUser Method with the creditentials.

You can then validate the user against your stored email/username and password
using the ValidateUser Method.

Hope that helps